# view.getMeasuredHeight() always returns same height android

Tags: android, listview

I have Listview having comment listing with different height of each row according to comment length. I want to give height to the listview programmatically. I tried to get height of each row, but every time I get the same height for each row.. but each row has different size according to their content. I have used following code:

```
 ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter != null) {

        int numberOfItems = listAdapter.getCount();

        // Get total height of all items.
        int totalItemsHeight = 0;
        for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < numberOfItems; itemPos++) {
            View item = listAdapter.getView(itemPos, null, listView);
            item.measure(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

            totalItemsHeight += item.getMeasuredHeight();
            Log.e("HEIGHT", "" + item.getMeasuredHeight());
        }

        // Get total height of all item dividers.
        int totalDividersHeight = listView.getDividerHeight() *
                (numberOfItems - 1);

        // Set list height.
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalItemsHeight + totalDividersHeight;
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();


    }
```

Comment: Have you set a fixed height to your list item in XML?

Comment: Check if you have given fixed height in xml ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for it to be laid out and measured.

If you want to force it to do this early for an item which wraps content you can call measure like this:

```
item.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(maxWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(maxHeight, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
```

Before calling `getMeasuredHeight`. Remember though, that this will return pixels not dp so you may need to do some conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  ViewTreeObserver :

```
int mViewHeight =WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

    callAddOnGlobalLayoutListner(item);


    Method ::
    public void callAddOnGlobalLayoutListener(final View v){
            view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                        @Override
                        public void onGlobalLayout() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            v.getViewTreeObserver()
                                    .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                             mViewHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();
    Log.d("Height",mViewHeight+"");

                            }

                        }
                    });
        }
```